# centering div fixed position -no solution worked

Tags: html, css

I just want to make a preloader that's positioned in the middle of the page.
Requirements:

- position: fixed;
- centered on the X-axis

It's just a div with class 'preloader' in body. Body is this div's direct parent, no other wrapper in between.

```
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    -ms-transform: translateX(100px); /*100px just to test if it moved at all, initially had -50%, see list below*/
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
    transform: translateX(100px);
//=====rest is just animation and aesthetics======
    border: 3px solid #8A2EE6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5) inset, 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5);
    animation-name: rotatePreloader;
    animation-duration: 0.65s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

I've done:

- display: block;
- display: inline-block;
- translateX(-50%);
- translateX(30px);
- translate(-50%, 0);
- translate(30px, 0);
- translate(-50%, -50%);
- rearranging the transforms.. lol
- took off -o & -mos
- margin: 0 auto (worked with position: relative when I didn't need it to be fixed)

https://jsfiddle.net/goa3v2ke/#

Comment: Add your code to jsfiddle and provide the link .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like this, where you set `top`/`left` to 50% and then move them back with `translate` using the same value, int this case -50%.

Sample 1 now center it both horizontal and vertical, and by change the `top`/`left` values, you can move it in the direction you want, sample 2 has 33% as `top` value.

---

**Update based on question edit**

The small X/Y-axis offset is caused by the `rotate` being executed before the `translate`, so change your `@keyframes` rule to this, showed in sample 3 and an [update of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goa3v2ke/1/)

```
@keyframes rotatePreloader {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

---

Sample 1

```css
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  
/*=====rest is just animation and aesthetics======*/
    border: 3px solid #8A2EE6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5) inset, 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5);
    animation-name: rotatePreloader;
    animation-duration: 0.65s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader"></div>
```

Sample 2

```css
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 33%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  
/*=====rest is just animation and aesthetics======*/
    border: 3px solid #8A2EE6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5) inset, 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5);
    animation-name: rotatePreloader;
    animation-duration: 0.65s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader"></div>
```

Sample 3

```css
.leftPreloaderBG {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 98;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.leftPreloaderBG.loaded {
  width: 0;
}

.rightPreloaderBG {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 98;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.rightPreloaderBG.loaded {
  width: 0;
}

@keyframes rotatePreloader {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 33%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /*=====rest is just animation and aesthetics======*/
  border: 3px solid #8A2EE6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5) inset, 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5);
  animation-name: rotatePreloader;
  animation-duration: 0.65s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.preloader.loaded {
  opacity: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: gray;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="preloader"></div>
  <div class="leftPreloaderBG"></div>
  <div class="rightPreloaderBG"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: what you told me, I've tried as listed. "translate(-50%, 0)"
here's what I have and it doesn't work with the other 2 divs whether I put preloader before or after them.
https://jsfiddle.net/goa3v2ke/#

Comment: @reddtoric That is caused by the `rotate`. Here is an update of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/goa3v2ke/1/ ... note the added `translate(-50%, -50%)` to your `@keyframes`

Answer (score 1):

It is because you override the transform translate value in the keyframe animation. Try it like this:

```css
.leftPreloaderBG {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 98;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.leftPreloaderBG.loaded {
  width: 0;
}

.rightPreloaderBG {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 98;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.rightPreloaderBG.loaded {
  width: 0;
}

@keyframes rotatePreloader {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 33%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /*=====rest is just animation and aesthetics======*/
  border: 3px solid #8A2EE6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5) inset, 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5);
  animation-name: rotatePreloader;
  animation-duration: 0.65s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.preloader.loaded {
  opacity: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: gray;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="preloader"></div>
  <div class="leftPreloaderBG"></div>
  <div class="rightPreloaderBG"></div>
</body>
```